# Interrupts Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is a code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _sevenForDisplay.length; i++) {

    _sevensForReplace = [_sevensForReplace stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([[_sevenForDisplay substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)] intValue]-1,1) withString:@"1"];

    NSOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                              initWithTarget:self
                              selector:@selector(blinkPicSeven:)
                              object:@(_forBlink)];

    [queue addOperation:operation];

}

[userDefaults setObject:_sevensForReplace forKey:@"sevens"];
```

When the code is carried out in the course of work of the program, a error on the last line with the message - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7a0090018).

I start debugging step by step (I become at the beginning of a cycle and further on F6), everything passes normally.

In the old OSX and Xcode version everything worked correctly, doesn't work in the new version. (the project stood a floor of year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you  `[[NSString alloc]init]` your `_sevensForReplace` before forge a value to it. It seems now, and especially on XCode 6.+ with SDK selected as 8.2 those `NSString` which are **not** allocated (init) seems to crash app, despite this measure was not really necessary before 8.2

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to alloc,init you can use it this way :

```
[self setSevensForReplace:[[self sevensForReplace] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([[[self sevensForReplace] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)] intValue]-1,1) withString:@"1"]];
```